# Issues creating DATETIME for date (DATE) and time (INT) how to fix?

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, openedge, progress-db

Working from a Progress ODBC and inputting the data to Excel. Currently in the Event Table i have an Object for Created Date and another for Created time. I am looking at concatenating these two together to create a date time.

I have tried an number of different things already and looked through stack for your standard resolves but for some reason i cant seem to get them to work as i intended if at all.

The data is currently set out like this

```
EventID      EVECreateddate         EVECreatedTime
  123          29/04/2019              59302
```

As you can see from the data the created time when exported does not show as the time it should. In the DB the `EVECreatedTime` is an `INTERGER` and the `EVECreateddate` is a `DATE`.

In order for the `EVECreatedtime` to show as an actual time i have to complete the following:

```
Cast(Event_0.EveCreatedTime AS DECIMAL)/86400 AS'EveCreatedTime'
```

This is then formatted at the front end as `[h]:MM:SS` to display this as an actual time.

Now i have it in a time format i try to complete the following:

```
Event_0.EveCreatedDate + CAST(Event_0.EveCreatedTime AS Decimal)/86400 as testing
```

The data now returns under a General format like:

```
EventID        TESTING
  123           43585
```

When you convert the formatting to `DD:MM:YY [h]:mm:ss` it will look like:

```
29/04/2019 12:00:00
```

So it is showing the correct date but not the right time.

I have also tried:

```
Event_0.EveCreatedDate + Event_0.EveCreatedTime
```

Which returns an inflated date such as: `16/07/2122 00:00:00` when formatted `DD:MM:YY hh:mm:ss`

I then try to complete:

```
Event_0.EveCreatedDate + ' ' + Event_0.EveCreatedTime
```

This errors with a Inconsistent types (7481) which makes me think it cant be done in Progress.

Any help around this even if its to be told it cant be done because of the limitations would be helpful. All i would like if possible is to return a datetime for each event looking like this:

```
  Event ID                  EventDatetime
     123                  29/04/2019 16:28:22
```

Comment: 59302/86400 is 16:28:22 as a time, so I'm confused as to where 12:09:32 comes from?

Comment: EVECreatedTime is most probably assigned with the TIME function in Progress. This means it is in seconds. I don't know how this works in Excel, but perhaps you can display the time when you know it is seconds as from 00:00:00.

Comment: @HarassedDad sorry i wasnt consistent with my use of time examples you are correct i will amend above to make it clearer

Comment: Try explicitly casting  to a double as that's what Excel expects a date/time to be 
 CAST(( Event_0.EveCreatedDate + CAST(Event_0.EveCreatedTime AS Decimal)/86400) as double).

Comment: Try combining the fields on the DB Side and (if nececcary) cast them as DATETIME. If I was using mySQL, I would write it like this (tested!) `SELECT ADDTIME(evecreateddate , sec_to_time(evecreatedtime)) FROM test`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [timestampadd](https://documentation.progress.com/output/DataDirect/odbcsparksqlhelp/index.html#page/odbcspark/date-and-time-functions.html) function:

```
timestampadd( sql_tsi_second, EveCreatedTime, EveCreatedDate ) "timestamp"
```

The timestamp in Excel is then shown as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM - this custom format can be changed to include seconds.

(tested with Progress OpenEdge 11.7.4)